# Shopify - How to exclude a collection in paginate?

Tags: shopify

I need to exclude a collection inside the paginate loop. But if I use the conditional statement, it will still be counted in paginate count.

So If I paginate by 10 and there are 2 products from the excluded collection in first page, I will only see 8 products in first page.

Any solution for this? Here's my snippet:

```
{% paginate collection.products by 10 %}
  <ul>
  {% for product in collection.products %}

    <!-- Check for collection -->
    {% assign is_treatment = false %}
    {% for c in product.collections %}
      {% if c.handle == "salon-treatment" %}
        {% assign is_treatment = true %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% unless is_treatment %}
      <li>{{ product.title }}</li>
    {% endunless %}

  {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endpaginate %}
```

Note: This question is duplicated from [the one I posted in Shopify forum](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/how-to-exclude-a-collections-in-paginate-196387).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did for something like this was first load in all the *desired* products into a collection of my own (basically an array of objects), and then paginate THAT array... so, if you write a function called *exclude_some_products* which returns all the unexcluded products, do this:

```
{% assign my_smaller_collection = exclude_some_products collection %}
{% paginate my_smaller_collection.products by 10 %}
  <ul>
  {% for product in my_smaller_collection.products %}

    <!-- Check for collection -->
    {% assign is_treatment = false %}
    {% for c in product.collections %}
      {% if c.handle == "salon-treatment" %}
        {% assign is_treatment = true %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% unless is_treatment %}
      <li>{{ product.title }}</li>
    {% endunless %}

  {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endpaginate %}
```

p.s. pardon my code, I'm not even sure what language this is!

Comment: Wow, I didn't know we can paginate array. I'll try this next time.